# Listing like appstore in firefox or any other browser for windows/desktop linux

Tags: android, firefox, list, app-store

A little question about the listing in iPhone OS and some other applications, and possibly in Android Market. 
When listing the apps, it fills the list in an automatic process, when reaching or is near to reach the end.

My question is: How is that written in iPhone applications. But the main question is: Is that possible to make for Firefox users with Javascript, Ajax or possibly any other language? Been looking a little bit in documentation but havent found anything useful, maybe I just havent looked enough

**edit:** Found it for Android - [Dynamic ListView in Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917773/dynamic-listview-in-android-app) 
Still looking for same futures for a Windows browser tho
out

**edit2:** im looking to implement it in a website 
with a list of books + some info.

Answer (score 1):

You want Javascript. There are plenty of examples packaged as Greasemonkey scripts that turn Google search results into an endless scrolling list. I hesitate to offer a specific code example since I'm not quite sure what you're after. Are you looking to deploy that sort of script on a website you're building, or are you looking at making someone else's page do this with your own script?