# multiple listview in single activity dynamically

Tags: android, listview

How can we create multiple listview dynamically in single activity please provide me any code....

Comment: multiple listview means ? 2 or more listviews in one screen ?

Comment: yes...i want to show more than 2 listviews in one screen and every listview should have heading...

Comment: can u provide any sample screenshot?

Comment: Demo of List View listone: Basic Information --> name,address,about me.        listtwo: Education--> collage,course,year   listthree: Contact Information--> phone no, mobile no,city, country.

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 Linear layouts side by side , say orientation as horizontal(give id's to the layout) , create a listview dynamically in code and attach those 2 listviews to your layouts.

like,

```
Listview lv1 = new ListView();   
ListView lv2 = new ListView();

// get reference to your layouts    
LinearLayout lL1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutId1);    
LinearLayout lL2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutId2);

// attach the ListView objects to the LinearLayouts
lL1.addview(lv1);   
lL2.addview(lv2);
```

This should get you started.

Comment: I am getting lists from the webservice show and that list will be dynamic that means it may be 2 3 or more than that. so, i have to create listview dynamically....

Comment: Its better to fix some fixed layouts before you can populate the results.

Comment: can you provide me some demo code of "dynamically create listview"??

Comment: Dynamically creating listview is similar to as I have shown in the soln , I am not sure what you are looking after , to add rows dynamically to listview , you can check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917773/dynamic-listview-in-android-app

Comment: i am looking for "add more than one listview with respective contents not only content"

Comment: Demo of List View listone: Basic Information --> name,address,about me. listtwo: Education--> collage,course,year listthree: Contact Information--> phone no, mobile no,city, country