# Help regarding ListView

Tags: android, listview

I got a ListView with TextView in it.

Upon Clicking the ListView Item, I want to add a Layout(.xml file) with a single ListView item pushing the next ListView items below. The layout is just a ListView item with TextView and a Button.

Is it possible to generate such a scenario ??

Thanks,

Siva Kumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is get the adapter from the listview and add items to this adapter. You can refer to the following question asked here previously

[Dynamic ListView in Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917773/dynamic-listview-in-android-app)

Comment: But I dint understand that code completely !!
can you just briefly tell what are resource files there ??

Comment: Are you referring to CustomAdapter constructor params? If yes checkout ArrayAdapter in android at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E%29