# Implementing ListView with icons on different items in android application

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which i have to place 5 items with 5 icons in a list.Has anyone implemented it before?

If Yes,Can he help me how to implement it?

Thanks 
tushar

Comment: you need to careate dynamic listview in android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917773/dynamic-listview-in-android-app

Comment: @scorpio thanks,,But do u have a sample code?

Comment: What do you mean by "sample code"? The linked question has it.

Comment: ok,,,i mean to say,,i got ur point,,,,and will try out some samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try from this
[Dynamic ListView in Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917773/dynamic-listview-in-android-app)

```
 public class ListViewDemo extends ListActivity {


//LIST OF ARRAY STRINGS WHICH WILL SERVE AS LIST ITEMS
ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();

//DEFINING STRING ADAPTER WHICH WILL HANDLE DATA OF LISTVIEW
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

//RECORDING HOW MUCH TIMES BUTTON WAS CLICKED
int clickCounter=0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

super.onCreate(icicle);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
listItems);
setListAdapter(adapter);
}

//METHOD WHICH WILL HANDLE DYNAMIC INSERTION
public void addItems(View v) {
listItems.add("Clicked : "+clickCounter++);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

> android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 is default list items layout supplied by android and >you can use this stock layout for non complex things.
>
> listItems is an array list which holds the data shown in the ListView and all the >insertion and removal should be done on listItems the changes in list should reflect in >the view and thats handled by ArrayAdapter adapter which should be notified using

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

> Adapter is instantiated with 3 paramters the context which could be your >activity/listactivity the layout of you individual list item and lastly the list which is >the actual data to be displayed in the list.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <Button android:id="@+id/addBtn"
    android:text="Add New Item" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="addItems"/>
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    /></LinearLayout>

Comment: thanks,,,,very much,,its only code u have posted ,,can i run it,,will it work fine?