# listview view error

Tags: android

am doing chat app in which i want to display photo,adaptermodel,small icon for online status in listview

this gives error:

```
final List<AttendeeModel> attendeesList = getAttendeesList(
                    attendees, sender);

            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<AttendeeModel>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, attendeesList,R.layout.row, R.id.icon));
```

how simple i implement this..

thanks in advance...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917773/dynamic-listview-in-android-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use BaseAdapter for that..
example link 
[link example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html)

please see the example and if you cant understand then tell me