# How to add TextViews to a ListView

Tags: android

I have a list and I would like to dynamically add rows to this list, but I want every row to be a TextView. Is this possible?

The following code doesn't work because it tells me that the method addView(TextView) is undefined for the type ArrayList (listItems):

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText("sample text");
listItems.addView(textView);
```

Which is the correct way to add text views to a list then?

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917773/dynamic-listview-in-android-app

Comment: I've read the article, but I don't know if I understood how it can be applied to my question: basically it says that if I want to add a TextView I should say so in the private class RowData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link in the comment is very helpful.

But to explain here, basically, you don't add *textViews* to the ArrayList, you add *elements* to the ArrayList and the listAdapter will automatically put time into the listView.  Also, you might need to call *invalidate* on the view to force it to update.

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing right now: I am adding strings to the ArrayList, I was wondering if it was better to add text views instead :)

Comment: I was wondering: if, like you say, I add an element to a ListView, is this automatically transformed into a view?