# Database retrieval in android

Tags: android, database

In my application i am showing data from database in a table view.My requirement is that from database i have to retrieve the data which will fall in the current month.I Have written the query but it is coming as 0.Actually i have  1 entry in the database   with today's date,so my query should return that data,but it is showing as 0.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

My query is as follows:

```
public String addgroupincome(String grp) throws SQLException
{   
    long sum=0; 
    Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery(
             "SELECT SUM("+(KEY_TOTAL)+") FROM incomexpense WHERE date= Strftime('%Y-%m','now') AND category='Income' AND groups='"+grp+"'",null);
     if(cursor1.moveToFirst())
     {
       sum = cursor1.getLong(0);
     }
     cursor1.close();   
     String housetotal=String.valueOf((long)sum);    
     return housetotal; 
}
```

I am getting that total and showing in atextview in table layout..

```
final  String houtotal=db.addgroupincome(group1);  
     housetotal.setText(houtotal);
```

Comment: have you checked by cursor1.getCount() ?

Comment: S nick...Its is coming as 1..

Comment: It's mean that you are getting the data from the database. Now check how you are dealing with the data.

Comment: Nick That is the problem...Now i just summed up the total column and returned that..But it is coming as 0 y??????

Comment: Nick one more thing..Now i added 1 more data in today's date.So 2 datas are available in database with today's date,now the cursor count should return as 2 ,but now also it is coming as 1..

Comment: No no.please don't do this. Let me check first.

Comment: Dear. I have less knowledge of query. First make sure that your query is confirmed right.

Comment: Ya i also have doubt in that only..I am also little bit new to this..But another person say's its correct..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14724/discussion-between-nick-and-prakash-k)

Comment: @prakash, you might need sqlite browser to help you with your query.Try http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/ or http://www.sqliteexpert.com/

Answer (score 0):

Most probably nothing wrong with the query but the way you pass the query result to ListView. Can you show how you do it? Perhaps I could help.

Or you could take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917773/dynamic-listview-in-android-app) or [here](http://wowjava.wordpress.com/2011/03/26/dynamic-listview-in-android/)

---

```
public int getCount() {
    DBHelper dbHelper = DBHelper.getDBAdapterInstance(this);
    int count = 0;

    try {
        dbHelper.openDataBase();

        String query = "select count(1) from t_model where upper(brandName) = upper('"
                + selectedBrand + "') order by modelName ASC";

        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.selectRecordsCursor(query, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            count = cursor.getInt(0);
        }

        cursor.close();
        cursor = null;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    return count;
}
```

and for the TextView should be as simple as

```
TextView tvCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCount);
tvCount.setText("Count : " + getCount);
```

---

If you are having trouble debugging your query. Try http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/ or http://www.sqliteexpert.com/

Comment: Sorry halim..not listview its table layout...sorry i done a mistake in my question..Anyway i will post my code ,..

Comment: Ok first make sure what value for String housetotal return 1 as expected. TableLayout should also be able to show value from db.

Comment: Halim...The housetotal should return the sum value,and i have to display that in a textview..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try by giving column names of your table in your query..might it work out for you..specify the columns which you want to retrive..

Answer (score 0):

```
if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
  cursor.moveToFirst();
  while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
    Log.i(ID, cursor.getInt(0) + "");
    cursor.moveToNext();
  }
  cursor.close();
} else {
  cursor.close();
  return null;
}
```

Try This Method....