# Adding text views into listView dynamically

Tags: android, listview, textview

I need to make a dynamic listView and a button that would add elements(textViews) to it when clicked. I have been trying to research about this, but didn't find much help, possibly because I am not so good at java and OOP at the current moment. I have found this link: [Dynamic ListView in Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917773/dynamic-listview-in-android-app) , but wasn't able to understand this fully.

Comment: It sounds like you have a lot to learn, there's nothing we can do or answer here that will teach you everything you need to know. It's up to you to look through answers like the one you linked in your question and any of the other many resources that can be found online.

Comment: @bwegs Hi! Thanks for your comment. I'll try to look into your advice, sounds like there is still a long road for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot you need to learn before tackling tasks as hard as these.